# shell: arithmetic with custom number bases

Tags: shell, sh, radix

I have to write a command line that take two numbers in two different custom base and output in a third one.

By custom base, I mean that I have things like that:

- Input base 1: "!?\
- Input base 2: ajedpoi
- Output: rAfeB oiX

So starting from that I guess that `bc` doesn't help, right?

Is there such a command or should I write some custom script? Could you give me some clues? I'm completly lost.

EDIT: the exercice exact instructions are:

> Write a command line that takes numbers from variables FT_NBR1, in
> ’"?! base, and FT_NBR2, in mrdoc base, and displays the sum of both
> in gtaio luSnemf base.

In a way that with the following values:

```
FT_NBR1=\'?"\"'\
FT_NBR2=rcrdmddd
```

I would get the following output:

```
Salut
```

Comment: What's that for *bases*?  How did you go from this two inputs to the output??

Comment: it's a shell exercice. instead of standard normal numbers and alphabetically ordered letters, I have some weird char list. And then I have to do an addition between two numbers expressed in that "bases" and the output is another string based on the third "base". I had now the exercice instructions.

Comment: 1) You listed two inputs, but you would need five: number 1, base of number 1, number 2, base of number 2, output base. It's not even clear which of these five your two inputs are. 2) The POSIX shell is a poor choice of language to accomplish this.

Comment: I have no choice but doing it with the posix shell.

Comment: Then why are you asking about `bc`?

Comment: sorry I wanted to mean posix shell and "coreutils". well the command line tools that are available on macos. like find, grep, awk, rev, bc, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was'nt clever enough. I can do it with just `tr` and `bc`

I use `tr` to convert from and back the weird "bases" and `bc` with normal numbers.

Here's what I have done:

```
#!/bin/sh
NUM1=$(echo "$FT_NBR1" | tr \'\\\\\"\?\! '01234')
NUM2=$(echo "$FT_NBR2" | tr mrdoc '01234')
RES=$(echo "obase=13; ibase=5; $NUM1 + $NUM2" | bc)

echo $RES | tr '0123456789abc' 'gtaio luSnemf'
```

Answer (score 1):

How would one convert the string `789` into a number?

Well, 789 is equal to

7 × 10<sup>2</sup> + 8 × 10<sup>1</sup> + 9 × 10<sup>0</sup>

But we're writing a program and we'll want to take advantage of looping.

( ( 7 ) × 10 + 8 ) × 10 + 9

Better yet,

( ( ( 0 ) × 10 + 7 ) × 10 + 8 ) × 10 + 9

We don't start with digits `7`, `8` and `9`, but their string representation.

```
(
   (
      (
         0
      ) × 10 + [ offset of "7" in "0123456789" ]
   ) × 10 + [ offset of "8" in "0123456789" ]
) × 10 + [ offset of "9" in "0123456789" ]
```

And finally, let's remove the last bit of reliance on base 10.

```
(
   (
      (
         0
      ) × [ number of symbols in "0123456789" ] + [ offset of "7" in "0123456789" ]
   ) × [ number of symbols in "0123456789" ] + [ offset of "8" in "0123456789" ]
) × [ number of symbols in "0123456789" ] + [ offset of "9" in "0123456789" ]
```

So the code would look like this:

1. Set `n` to 0.
2. Set `base` to the number of symbols in the base.
3. For each digit,

   1. Set `n` to the result of the multiplication of `n` and `base`.
   2. Get the offset of the digit in the array of symbols that make up the base.
   3. Set `n` to the result of the addition of `n` and the offset.

Example Perl implementation:

```perl
my @syms = split //, "01234567890";
my %sym_offset = map { $syms[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#syms; 

my $s = "...";

my $n = 0;
for my $sym ( split //, $s ) {
   my $offset = $sym_offset{ $sym };
   $n = $n * @syms + $offset;
}

$s = $syms[ 0 ] if !length( $s );

say $n;
```

---

The opposite of this process can be taken to take a number and convert it to base. Instead of repeatedly multiplying, one would repeatedly divide, using the remainder as an index into the list of symbols that make up the base.

1. Set `base` to the number of symbols in the base.
2. Set `s` to an empty string.
3. While `n` is greater than zero,

   1. Find the remainder of `n` divided by `base`.
   2. Get the symbol found at the offset equal to the remainder.
   3. Prepend the symbol to `s`.
   4. Set `n` to the result of the subtraction of the remainder from `n`.
   5. Set `n` to the result of the division of `n` by `base`.
4. If `s` is an empty string,

   1. Set `s` to the first symbol.

Example Perl implementation:

```perl
my @syms = split //, "01234567890";
my %sym_offset = map { $syms[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#syms; 

my $n = ...;

my $s = "";
while ( $n ) {
   my $offset = $n % @syms;
   $s = $syms[ $offset ] . $s;
   $n = ( $n - $offset ) / @syms;
}

say $n;
```